# Nautilus does 't open in Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, gnome3, nautilus

The command `nautilus` does't show any window and does't return.
There is no error message.

I tried `apt purge nautilus && apt install nautilus` and reboot without any success.

I am using `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` and `Gnome 3.30.2`.

My more general question is how to track this kind of issue? Is there any log file where gnome prints warnings and errors?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `nautilus` took around 30min to finally open...

I think I found the issue.

The program `tracker` was using a lot of CPU and RAM.
Not only `nautilus` was very long to open, but all my computer was very slow (to open `firefox`, `gedit`..., enter some text, switch windows...).
I remembered that I recently downloaded around 10G of data contained in several
millions of `txt` files.

I removed these files and everything runs fine now!